# I have a simple code written in flutter . and now I want to format it . I use VSC and I installed Prettier

Tags: android, flutter, dart, visual-studio-code, format

Help me to format the style code like this :

[image]

I have searched google and youtube a lot but I still can't do it, please guide me in detail

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think flutter doesn't support this format style, you should use Flutter default format style because most companies use it like that.

Comment: ok. thanks Minh Nguyên. I'm new to flutter so I'm not familiar with the coding style. but i think it will be fine

Comment: anh có thể cho em lại 1 cái useful được không heh

Answer (score 0):

You cannot format Flutter code with Prettier, prettier is only generally used for html/css/javascript/ts files.

Please install the flutter extension if you want flutter formatting and other flutter features in VSCode

[flutter for vscode](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=Dart-Code.flutter)

[read more about : Automatically formatting code in VS Code](https://flutter.dev/docs/development/tools/formatting#automatically-formatting-code-in-vs-code)

[Using Visual Studio Code for Flutter Development](https://flutter.dev/docs/development/tools/vs-code)

Comment: Thank you . If i want to a custom format did flutter support ?

Comment: Yes you can, check the options for the extension.

[This video might](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=nAmOt5_fMtU) help